# Existence of Solution of a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Suppose, $Ax=b$ does not admit any solution for some $n*n$ matrix & some b in $R^n$.Does it imply $A^tx=b$ also not admit solution ?

I think it may admit solution but I am unable to find out counter example. pls anyone help me.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried to find a counterexample?  Try almost any non-symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrix with rank $1$.

Comment: Usually the images  of $A$ and $A^t$ are different for a noninvertible and nonsymmetric matrix.

Comment: yes sir i got it

Answer (score 1):

*Counterexample:*

Consider the linear system
$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -2\\ -1 & -2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$
for which *there isn't solution*, that is, is inconsistent.

However, the linear system
$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -2\\ -1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}^{T} \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 2\end{bmatrix} \text{equivalent to} \quad \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1\\ -2 & -2 \end{bmatrix}^{T} \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$
has *infinitely many solutions*, that is, is consistent.